# What's this mean? $ ./your_program <dino>wilma

Tags: linux, shell, putty

I don't understand the meaning of:

```
$ ./your_program <dino>wilma
```

I'm learning perl, and I do not understand how to do this. I am using PUTTY.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag!

Comment: There's no Perl here at all. This is about standard Unix (or Linux) shell features.

Comment: Easy question, but looking at the wrong place. Read a little into Unix shell. The $ sign means, you are executing a script as super user ./ runs the program "your_program" with the parameters given. Commands like this are meant to be typed into a console window. DON'T DO THIS if you don't know what it is doing!

Answer (score 3):

The `$ ./your_program` indicates that you should run a program *your_program* on your shell. It assumes you have Linux. The `$` indicates your command prompt.

So if you have a Windows machine and a server or another computer with Linux that you connect to with PuTTY, you need to write your program on that machine.

Then you need to make it executable.

```
$ chmod u+x your_program
```

Now you can run it. Running a program that is executable in Linux is done by typing the name of the program into the shell. You just did that with `chmod`, and maybe with `vim` or `emacs` when you created the file. But because your program is not accessible from everywhere, you need to put the `./your_program` so the shell knows that you want to run it inside of the current directory. That's what the `.` is for.

```
$ ./your_program wilma
```

The `wilma` is a command line argument. It will be passed to your program.

You could also run it with the `perl` interpreter without making it executable.

```
$ perl your_program wilma
```

You can name all your Perl programs with `.pl` at the end so it's easier for you to distinguish what type of file they are.

Answer (score 2):

- `$` denotes the unix command prompt.
- `./` is the current path - by convention unix systems don't look for executable programs in the current working directory (the places it looks is defined by the `PATH` environment variable).
- `your_program` is the name of the file you just created/saved.
- The above will only work if your file is set "executable" - `chmod u+x your_program`. You can alternatively use `perl your_program` and achieve basically the same result.
- `<dino` means 'open the file "dino" and feed it into this program on the standard input. (`STDIN`).
- `>wilma` means open the file "wilma"; truncate it, and write the *output* of this program to this file.

`STDIN` is a unix concept that's 'standard input' - it can either be 'things you type' or the content of a file or command.

That might not make a lot of sense, but it's all about piping - you can:

cat file | grep someword | sed 's/oneword/anotherword/'

That opens a file ( with `cat`) filters all the lines containing `someword` and then does a pattern replacement on it.

`cat` will "send" `file` to `grep` on `STDIN`.

Comment: You've also not talked about the redirections, on `STDIN` of the file `dino` and the (clobbered) output to the file `wilma`.

Comment: Yes, had missed them due to edit formatting. Amended.

Comment: You can drop `cat` and just pass `file` to `grep` instead: `grep someword file | sed 's/oneword/anotherword/'`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a quotation from chapter 5.6 of *Learn Perl*, the whole quote is:

> ...In that way, the user can type a command like this one at the shell
>   prompt:
>
> ```
> $ ./your_program <dino >wilma
> ```
>
> That command tells the shell that the program's input should be read
>   from the file *dino*, and the output should go to the file *wilma*. As
>   long as the program blindly reads its input from *STDIN*, processes it
>   (in whatever way we need), and blindly writes its output to *STDOUT*,
>   this will work just fine.

http://perl.find-info.ru/perl/027/learnperl4-chp-5-sect-6.html

Perhaps a *Chinese* translation might be of use to the OP 文海梅:

http://www.biostatistic.net/thread-4903-1-1.html